# Java arrays and methods issues

Tags: java, arrays

I need my program to do the following below.

5. Create a function called toString that returns a printable string for the values of an array in “array literal format”.
6. Create a function called rangeInArray that returns the range of the values in the array. In math, the range is the magnitude of the difference between the minimum and maximum (inclusive). I already have methods for min and max to use them and do not need to include any loops for this method.

This is the code I have currently.

```
public class WestAndersonAsmnt9 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int Sample_Array_1[] = {4,7,9,3,2,8,15,6,8,7};
        int Sample_Array_2[] = {12,6,4,8,3,7,11,1,6};
        IntegerArray arr = new IntegerArray(Sample_Array_1.length);
        IntegerArray arr2 = new IntegerArray(Sample_Array_2.length);
        IntegerArray arr3 = new IntegerArray(Sample_Array_1);
        IntegerArray arr4 = new IntegerArray(Sample_Array_2);
        arr.fillRandom(100, 200);
        arr.printLiteral();
        arr2.fillRandom(100, 200);
        arr2.printLiteral();
        arr.copy(Sample_Array_1);
        arr.printLiteral();
        arr.copy(Sample_Array_2);
        arr.printLiteral();
        arr3.sumOfArray();
        arr4.sumOfArray();
        arr3.maxInArray();
        arr4.maxInArray();
        arr3.minInArray();
        arr4.minInArray();
        arr3.rangeInArray();


    }

}


public class IntegerArray {
    int arr[];

    public IntegerArray(int size) {
        arr = new int[size];
    }

    public IntegerArray(int value[]) {
        arr = value;
    }

    public void fillRandom(int from, int to) {
        int range = (to - from) + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = (int) (Math.random() * range) + from;
        }
    }

    public void printLiteral() {
        if (arr == null) {
            System.out.println("No array");
        } else if (arr.length <= 0) {
            System.out.println("{}");
        } else {
            System.out.print("{" + arr[0]);
            for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
                System.out.print("," + arr[i]);
            }
            System.out.println("}");
        }
    }

    public void copy(int copy[]) {
        arr = copy;
    }

    public void sumOfArray() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int counter = 0; counter < arr.length; counter++) {
            sum += arr[counter];
        }
        System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);

    }

    public int maxInArray() {
        int largest = arr[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) 
            if (arr[i] > largest) {
                largest = arr[i];
        }
        System.out.println("The max is " + largest);
        return largest
    }
    public int minInArray() {
        int smallest = arr[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
            if (arr[i] < smallest) {
                smallest = arr[i];
            }
        System.out.println("The mmin is " + smallest);
        return smallest
    }
    public int rangeInArray() {
    int range = maxInArray() - minInArray() + 1;  // + 1 for "inclusive"
    System.out.println("The range is " + range);
    return range;
    }

}
```

Comment: The PDF link is behind password protection, which makes your question unanswerable as it requires referring to the PDF.

Comment: Try simplifying this question down. No one wants to read that much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `maxInArray()` and `minInArray()` to return integer.

```
public int maxInArray() {
    int largest = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) 
        if (arr[i] > largest) {
            largest = arr[i];
    }
    System.out.println("The max is " + largest);
    return largest;
}

public int minInArray() {
    int smallest = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
        if (arr[i] < smallest) {
            smallest = arr[i];
        }
    System.out.println("The mmin is " + smallest);
    return smallest;
}

public int rangeInArray() {
    int range = maxInArray() - minInArray() + 1;  // + 1 for "inclusive"
    System.out.println("The range is " + range);
    return range;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, when I run that though, it doesn't give the range, it simply spits back the same results form the maxInArray and minInArray methods.

Comment: @Jetster220 Sorry.  I changed my code to suit your style.

Comment: Thanks, much better. Is there a way to not have it also state the max and min though?